# Create lines for list elements

Tags: css, tailwind-css

how can I do like this UI with css or tailwind?
It is a sidebar but the list items have curved lines going into them.

Here's an image of what I mean exactly:

[image: list items]

Comment: In a number of ways, where did you run into problems? What html have you come up with, what css have you tried to compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an approach in this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RuqYMH1x6q)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative bg-blue-700 text-white max-w-[16rem] p-4 pl-8">
  <div class="absolute left-4 top-4 h-6 border-l-2 border-b-2 w-4 rounded-bl-lg"></div>
  
  <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-white/20 rounded-xl">
    Manage Items
  </div>
  
  <div class="absolute left-4 top-4 h-[4.5rem] border-l-2 border-b-2 w-4 rounded-bl-lg"></div>
  
  <div class="px-4 py-3">
    Manage Categories
  </div>
  
</div>
```